# What is the internal energy of water vapor? OR How many degrees of freedom does $\rm H_2O$ have?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, water, molecules, degrees-of-freedom

Here are the "knowns" that I'm working with.

Internal Energy for a monatomic gas is

$$U = (3/2)nRT$$

For a diatomic gas its

$$U = (5/2)nRT$$

All of my textbooks and online sources indicate that it's a (1/2)nRT contribution from each degree of freedom. So monatomic gets 3 spatial degrees of freedom. Diatomic gets 3 spatial PLUS 2 rotational - rotation along primary axis does not represent any difference.

So my primary question is, **what is the internal energy of water vapor**? I would guess

$$U = (6/2)nRT$$

We ought to get one extra degree of rotational freedom. But I'm worried that I'm missing out on vibrational degrees of freedom.

Further inquiries:

- Why do we not account for the 1 degree of vibrational freedom in diatomic molecules?
- Do the vibrational degrees of freedom account for a negligible amount of the internal energy, or is it small, but significant?
- Do the vibrational degrees of freedom take up different proportions of the internal energy at different temperatures or pressures?

Comment: I don't know about the degrees of freedom, but the molar heat capacity (const. volume) of water vapor is 4.32R based on info from the web.  So, it's almost 9R/2.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398848/what-is-the-high-temperature-molar-heat-capacity-of-mathrmco-2-carbon-diox Especially, see the plot.